# Stateful alerts in Grafana

Tags: monitoring, grafana

In Grafana, is there any way to make stateful alerts? For example:

- Make an alert that triggers if there is any significant (say 5σ) deviation from recent historic trends.
- Make an alert that only retriggers if the condition has significantly (say 10×) worsened since the last time that the same alert was triggered.
- Make an alert that only triggers if an intermittent condition reoccurs many enough times in a sliding window, and only resets if it reoccurs few enough times in another sliding window.